# Set alarms after device was restarted

Tags: android, sqlite

why my alarms don't ring after device was restarted? I insert my alarms' times into SQLite database and set alarms again after device was restarted but this doesn't seem to be worked. What can I do to make my alarms ring at a time?
mySQLiteHelper.class:

```
public class mySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "alarms.db";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_ALARMS = "alarms";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_ALARM = "alarm";
    private static final  String KEY_NAME = "name";

    public mySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables"create table alarms ("
    //+ "id integer primary key,"
      //      + "alarm text,"
        //    + "name text," // added a ','
          //  + "alarmname text" + ");"
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALARMS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_ALARM + " TEXT, "
                +  KEY_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
        //String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALARMS + "("
           //     + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_ALARM + " TEXT, "
           //     +  KEY_NAME + " TEXT, UNIQUE ("+KEY_NAME+") ON CONFLICT REPLACE" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ALARMS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations"," + alarm.getName() +,name
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addAlarm(Alarm alarm) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String sql =
                "INSERT or replace " +
                        "INTO alarms (alarm,"+KEY_NAME+") " +
                        "VALUES("+ alarm.getAlarm() +  ",'" + alarm.getName() + "')";
        //String sql =
          //      "INSERT or replace INTO alarms (alarm,alarmname) VALUES("+ alarm.getAlarm() + ",'" + alarm.getName() + "')" ;
        db.execSQL(sql);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    String getAlarm(String alarmname) {
        String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_ALARMS + " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " =  \"" + alarmname + "\"";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        if (cursor.getCount()>0)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        String alarm = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ALARM));
        cursor.close();
        // return contact
        return alarm;
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteAlarm() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //db.delete(TABLE_ALARMS, KEY_ID + " = ?",Alarm alarm
          //      new String[] { String.valueOf(alarm.getID()) });
        db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_ALARMS);
        db.close();
    }


    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getAlarmsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ALARMS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int i = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return i;
    }
}
```

And Alarm.class:

```
public class Alarm {
    //private variables
    int _id;
    String _name;
    String _alarm;

    // Empty constructor
    public Alarm(String alarm,String alarmname){
        this._alarm = alarm;
        this._name = alarmname;
    }
    // constructor
    public Alarm(int id, String name, String alarm){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._alarm = alarm;
    }

    // constructor
    public Alarm(String alarm){
        this._alarm = alarm;
    }
    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }

    // getting phone number
    public String getAlarm(){
        return this._alarm;
    }
}
```

This is how I call addAlarm():

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker1.getCurrentMinute());
                calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,timePicker1.getCurrentHour());

                String alarm1 = Long.toString(calendar1.getTimeInMillis());
                mySQLiteHelper mySQLiteHelper = new mySQLiteHelper(MainActivity2.this);
                mySQLiteHelper.deleteAlarm();
                mySQLiteHelper.addAlarm(new Alarm(alarm1,"alarm1"));
```

And MyReceiver2.class:

```
public class MyReceiver2 extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MyReceiver2() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            //context.startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,StartReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,0,intent1,0);
            mySQLiteHelper mySQLiteHelper = new mySQLiteHelper(context);
            String alarm1 = mySQLiteHelper.getAlarm("alarm1");
            long alarm2 = Long.parseLong(alarm1);
                am.set(AlarmManager.RTC,alarm3,pi);
        }
    }
}
```

And also my AndroidManifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.amadey.myapplication" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher1"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Introduction"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity2"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".StartReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >

    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService2"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver2"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is your Receiver working at all? Do you have the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission in the manifest?

Comment: share your manifest file

Comment: have you also added this?
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: @mike-m Well, I'm trying to figure out does it work or not,and take a look I've added whole manifest file

Comment: @mustanser-iqbal I've edited my question and added entire manifest file

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Putting a log print in `onReceive()`? Or even a `Toast`?

Comment: @rusheel-jain Yes,I do have this permission. And I've edited my question, so, please take a look

Comment: @mike-m I added a toast in onReceive() and then tried to restart my device with this app but no toast appeared

Comment: Is `MyReceiver2` in the same directory as the `Introduction` Activity? Are you, by chance, forcibly stopping the app before you reboot?

Comment: @mike-m If you mean their packages then they are the same.And I do not stop the app before reboot.

Comment: why you have written these lines in reciever? 
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"

Comment: @mustanser-iqbal I don't know, just create a BroadcastReceiver by clicking right button mouse on folder with my classes and new and other and BroadcastReceiver and there enabled and exported are set by default

Comment: okay.well i am not sure but i think you need to add the following permission as well
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Comment: remove the constructor as well there is no need for that in broadcast receiver.

Comment: @mustanser-iqbal Well, I did all as you have said and now I'm trying to show my first activity after device was restarted but I got error that says that unfourtunatly my closed

Comment: @mustanser-iqbal Hey maaan, thank you so much, I finally did it.Can you please answer on this question and I will mark it as the best answer

Comment: @mustanser-iqbal But if my will be stored on the sd card I should add READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following things.

> add the folloing permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

> remove the constructor from receiver.
>
> But if my will be stored on the sd card I should add `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

if you want to read data from sd-card then you need to specifiy this permission. if you only want to write data on sd-card then there is no need for that. in that case you need `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission

Answer (score 0):

Beccause in android, if your device is re-booted, all the services/receivers that do not have BOOT_COMPLETED permission in the manifest file, will not be restarted. Since the receivers and services have now "died" after restart, there is no-one to listen to your 'pending intents' for alarms, no one to send a new pending intent and moreover upon restart these pending intents are also cleared. 
in short, use that permission in manifest and handle the restart-intent in your receiver.

Comment: can someone explain what did I wrote wrong here that I got a downvote, as then I would like to get my knowledge correct by reading up in correct direction.

Comment: It might be because `BOOT_COMPLETED` is the broadcast action. The permission is `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`. Or maybe it's because your answer is just a guess at this point. We don't know if the OP has that permission already or not. Some users don't like it when you post guesses as answers.

Comment: Ahh thanks. It seems that I forgot the correct name of the permission.

Comment: @rusheel-jain But there aren't have to be any pending intents to handle my new alarms because I create new pending intent and set a new alarm after device was restarted, am I right?

Comment: @S.Drumble4, yes that is true. What i intended to say is that if you have multiple alarms scheduled but before they can ring, you restart the phone, the "scheduled alarms" are not saved by the OS upon restart. One has to do it by themselves

Comment: @rusheel-jain And what if insert them into database and after restarting fetch all alarms and set them again?

Comment: @S.Drumble4, I should work. To me the code along with the manifest seems correct. Can you add a Log as top line in you onReceive() method and see if it even gets called?

So attach your phone to the computer, switch on Device Monitor in Android studio and then restart phone. Check if this Log gets printed.

Comment: @rusheel-jain Sorry, but I got my answer from Mustanser Iqbal